# Elasticsearch correct aggregations for faceted search

Tags: search, elasticsearch, facet, faceted-search

I want to offer a faceted search for the clothing products on some platform. As I already have Elasticsearch-based search functionality (simple query, only the name of the product), it would be nice to also implement the faceted search with ES.

This should be done with aggregations as facets are deprecated and one can also have nested aggregations.

However I cannot wrap my head around the millions of aggregations and which ones are the right for me - there is [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html), [filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html), [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html), [children](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html) and so on. And all of them seem suitable.

What I want to achieve may  sound pretty basic: I have different facets (**brand, condition, color**) each having different values. For some facets (brand) the user can select only one value. For others (color) the user is allowed to select up to 3 (as some clothes have more than one color).

---

I started with multi-field terms facet. Now the next natural step would be to convert this to a terms aggregation (reasons above) but multi-fields are not supported in terms aggregations.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "groupByBrandAndCondition" : {
            "terms" : {
                "fields" : ["brand", "condition"],
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am somehow missing some easy but crucial point here on how to proceed with having parallel multi level bucketing. Speaking in UI terms the user should be able to select something like:

- Brands (10)

  - A (7)
  - *B (3)* [X]
- Colors (5)

  - *Blue (3)* [X]
  - *Red (2)* [X]

Read: select A (7), Blue (3) **and** Red (2)

Answer (score 2):

I created basic mapping like this

```
POST your_index/your_type/_mapping
{
  "your_type": {
    "properties": {
      "product": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "brand": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "color": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I inserted some documents like this

```
PUT your_index/your_type/111
{
  "product" : "jeans" ,"brand" : "lee", "color" : "blue"
}

PUT your_index/your_type/1111
{
  "product" : "shoes" ,"brand" : "levi", "color" : "black"
}

And so on
```

Simple aggregation query like this

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "prod_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "brand_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "brand"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "color_agg": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "color"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will retrun

```
"aggregations": {
      "prod_agg": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "shoes",
               "doc_count": 4,
               "brand_agg": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "nike",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "color_agg": {
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                           "buckets": [
                              {
                                 "key": "blue",
                                 "doc_count": 2
                              },
                              {
                                 "key": "black",
                                 "doc_count": 1
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "levi",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "color_agg": {
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                           "buckets": [
                              {
                                 "key": "black",
                                 "doc_count": 1
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "jeans",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "brand_agg": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "lee",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "color_agg": {
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                           "buckets": [
                              {
                                 "key": "black",
                                 "doc_count": 1
                              },
                              {
                                 "key": "blue",
                                 "doc_count": 1
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "levi",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "color_agg": {
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                           "buckets": [
                              {
                                 "key": "black",
                                 "doc_count": 1
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

This could be used to populate UI search criteria.

Then If user wants to search for shoes, you could query

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "product": "shoes"
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "brand_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "color_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "color"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will give you

```
"aggregations": {
      "brand_agg": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "nike",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "color_agg": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "blue",
                        "doc_count": 2
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "black",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "levi",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "color_agg": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "black",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

or you could have them as separate buckets with query like

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "product": "shoes"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "brand_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      }
    },
    "color_agg" : {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will give you

```
"aggregations": {
      "color_agg": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "black",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "blue",
               "doc_count": 2
            }
         ]
      },
      "brand_agg": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "nike",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "levi",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Use `doc_count` value to tell users how many options they have.

Does this satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I would say that the very last part with the separate buckets is what represents the sample list at the end of my question. What I still don't quite get is how I can get user input (say selecting colors 'blue' AND 'red') and also providing buckets for the other fields. Am I overthinking this - is it just a combination of a search query + aggregation?

Comment: From the question you posted, I feel query + aggregation should satisfy most of your requirements.